# How do I insert a phram module?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module, dma

I need to directly write to and read from physical memory for my research and the only way I can think of doing it is with a kernel module. I found this generic device driver called [phram](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mtd/devices/phram.c) that I've been trying to use to map memory and then write to and read from it but I'm having trouble mapping more than ~1.5GB. In my 16GB system, I have the OS usage constrained to 500MB at 0x0. Here are my kernel parameters: `mem=500M memmap=500M@0`. When I try to load the phram module with more than ~1.5GB like this:

`sudo modprobe phram phram=test,500Mi,15Gi`

I get this error message:

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'phram': Input/output error`

And this in dmesg:

```
[  247.303346] modprobe:1402 conflicting memory types 1f400000-3df400000 write-back<->write-combining
[  247.303350] reserve_memtype failed [mem 0x1f400000-0x3df3fffff], track uncached-minus, req uncached-minus
[  247.303352] ioremap reserve_memtype failed -16
[  247.303376] phram: ioremap failed
[  247.303393] phram: `test,500Mi,15Gi' invalid for parameter `phram'
```

I can't find any documentation on phram other than the source code. From what I have researched ioremap() (the mapping call in phram) shouldn't have a max size so I don't know where the issue could be. The dmesg output is a little too cryptic for me so if somebody could at least translate it that would also be a significant help.

Thanks!

Comment: use /dev/mem http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html

Comment: /dev/mem only accesses memory allocated to the OS. So it will only read 0 to 500M. I need to read 500M to 16G.